# ASP MVC Model Binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I can't explain Model Binder behavior in this example:

```
enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female
}

@model Gender
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Index", new { gender = Model });

public ActionResult(string gender)
{
    ViewBag.Gender = gender;
    return View()
}
```

why it works — string gender argument in action correct get Enum type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because absolutely everything can be converted to a `string` by way of `object.ToString()`. Further, it happens on `Enum` that the conversion produces something useful; the text of the enumeration value's name.

The default binder can convert back and forth between these values, <strike>plus the numeric ones, in most cases.</strike>

Comment: thank you! but what does it mean, when you said that "numeric ones, in most cases" — when it default binder can't convert it?

Comment: "In most cases" was the incorrect wording, I think... since it's an untrue statement! The strings are what you want to use. That seems strange to me, as generally it's easier to convert between `int` and the `enum` in both directions with a simple cast, whereas `Enum.Parse()` isn't exactly intuitive.